# how update tableview json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I would like to update my tableview data after I changed the data in mysql database but it's not working.  In my parsejson function i tried with:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                    self.movies = movieArray
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Of course this is not working because this function is not in the tableviewcontroller so it doesn't recognize the tableview.  Is it possible  to reload the tableview from a function in another file than the tableviewcontroller and how?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

after you update your data, notify your tableviewController to updata it's model and reload your tableview after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Swift Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Parts of code will look like that:

DataLoader.swift

```
class DataLoader: NSObject {

    func uploadData(completion: ([AnyObject]) -> () ) {
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            let array = [1, 2, 3, 4] //load your data in background thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completion(array) //send completion in main thread
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    let dataLoader = DataLoader()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataLoader.uploadData {
            (any) in
            if let movieArray = any as? [Int] { //Here instead of [Int] should be your array of objects e.g. [Movies]
                print("result: \(movieArray)")
                self.movies = movieArray
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```